# KnockoutJS: Remove array of items from an array

Tags: knockout.js

I have a problem with knockoutJS i can't figure out

I have two observableArrays; One containing all available items and one containing all selected items.

How can i return a new array, that contains all the available items ( with all the selected items removed from it)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use `.filter` or `ko.utils.arrayFilter`, and `.indexOf` or equivalent:

```
this.remainingOptions = ko.computed(function(){
    return this.availableOptions().filter(function(option) {
        return this.selectedOptions().indexOf( option ) === -1;
    }.bind(this));
},this);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p3RMD/1/

Edit: Also see the [Knockout Projections](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2013/12/03/knockout-projections-a-plugin-for-efficient-observable-array-transformations/) plugin if you want more efficient `.map` and `.filter` methods on observableArrays

Answer (score 2):

The standard removeAll method should handle this. From documentation:

> myObservableArray.removeAll(['Chad', 132, undefined])  removes all
>   values that equal 'Chad', 123, or undefined and returns them as an
>   array

Do you need to extract the  available items without altering the original, all available items array?

Comment: Yes, thats right.. i need the original allAvailableArray to be untouched

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return a new array, without modifying the original array, your best bet is to use a computed observable.

```
var ViewModel = function(){
    this.available = ko.observableArray([1,2,3,4,5]);
    this.selected = ko.observableArray([1,3,5]);

    this.remaining = ko.computed(function(){
        var remaining = ko.observableArray();
        remaining(ko.toJS(this.availableOptions))
        remaining.removeAll(this.selectedOptions());
        return remaining();
    }, this);
}
```

Here's a link to a working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/nathanjones/p3RMD/

*Edit:* fixed sample code.

Comment: Hmm.. that is not quite working as i would expect it to. What i need is the ObservableArray "available" to be untouched. and "remaining" containing the values "2,4".

Comment: It looks like there was an issue with accessing availableOptions directly. The updated code sample above should work. Check the jsFiddle, I believe it returns what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

Since my specific problem, was observableArrays containing objects ( which i failed to state in my question ). The answers provided did not fix my problem, although, it did answer the question nicely, which is why i am not changing answer.

for anyone interested in how i solved the problem, here is the code:

```
    var self = this;
    self.users = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.roles = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.selectedUser = ko.observable();

    self.remainingOptions = ko.computed(function () {
        return (self.roles()).filter(function (option) {
            var current = option.Name();
            var keep = true;
            if (self.selectedUser() !== undefined) {
                ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.selectedUser().Roles(), function (item) {

                    if (keep) {
                        keep = (current !== item.Name());
                    }
                    return (current === item.Name());
                });
            }
            return keep;
        }); //end  filter
    }); //end remaininOptions
```

the Role object is just an object with a Name property.